# Why does .ords not agree with .chars?

Tags: unicode, raku

My understanding of `.chars` is that it returns ["the number of characters in the string in graphemes"](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str#routine_chars).  My understanding of `.ords` is that it returns ["a list of codepoint numbers, one for the base character of each grapheme in the string"](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str#method_ords).  That is, `.chars` returns the number of graphemes and `.ords` returns one codepoint (the base) per grapheme.  However, the behavior I am seeing in Rakudo 2016.07.1 on MoarVM 2016.07 doesn't seem to match that:

```
> "\x[2764]\x[fe0e]".chars
1
> "\x[2764]\x[fe0e]".ords.fmt("U+%04x")
U+2764 U+fe0e
> "e\x[301]".ords.fmt("U+%04x")
U+00e9
> "0\x[301]".ords.fmt("U+%04x")
U+0030
```

The `.chars` method returns the expect 1 for the HEAVY BLACK HEART and VARIATION SELECTOR-15 (text representation ❤︎ rather than emoji ❤️, U+2764 U+fe0f), but then `.ords` returns both codepoints rather than just the base (I expected just U+2764).  Even more confusing, if you call `.ords` on LATIN SMALL LETTER E and COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT, you get back U+00e9 (LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE).  I was expecting U+0065 as LATIN SMALL LETTER E is the base codepoint.  I do get back the expected result when there isn't an NFC version of the string (eg U+0030 for 0́).

Is my understanding of `.chars` and `.ords` just flawed, or is this a bug?

Comment: Looks like a bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Documentation bug regarding the .ords method. One of the core developers has just updated the docs with this commit:

https://github.com/perl6/doc/commit/12ec5fc35e

Which should appear on the site shortly.